# Apache camel mybatis mapper xml

Tags: xml, apache-camel, mybatis

is it possible to create from any select a generic xml document? I mean I want to create for example something like this:

```
 <query>
    <row>
        <field>
           <nameOfField>[name of field from table here]</nameOfField>
           <valueOfField>[value of field from table here]</valueOfField>    
        </field>
    </row>
    <row>
        <field>
            (...)
        </field>
    </row>
</query>
```

A little example:

```
 query: SELECT firstName, lastName from employee;

 <query>
    <row>
        <field>
           <nameOfField>firstName</nameOfField>
           <valueOfField>Joe</valueOfField> 
        </field>

        <field>
            <nameOfField>lastName</lastName>
            <valueOfField>Pesci</lastName>
        </field>
    </row>
    <row>
        <field>
           <nameOfField>firstName</nameOfField>
           <valueOfField>Martin</valueOfField>  
        </field>

        <field>
            <nameOfField>lastName</lastName>
            <valueOfField>Larson</lastName>
        </field>
    </row>
</query>
```

As you can see I don't care about name of table. Just about fields na their values. Is it possible to create generic document xml like this depends only on fields from select?